# In C#, how can I see if the first character in an account is a specific value?

Tags: c#, contains

I have a string that contains a 15 digit account number.  The first digit cannot be a 0,1, 8 or 9.
I want to say something like:

```
public bool ValidateAccountNumber(string Accountnumber )
{
    char[] Invalidboro = new char[] { '0', '1', '8', '9'};
    bool returnValue = true;

    if (Accountnumber.Length != 15 || Accountnumber.Substring(1, 1).Contains(Invalidboro))
    {
        returnValue = false;
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

I'm new to C# and not sure how to do this.

Comment: string Invalidboro = "0189".
Invalidboro.Contains(Accountnumber[0]);

Comment: Other notes: `Substring(1, 1)` will get the 2nd character since indexes start at `0`. Also, no need for `returnValue`. You can simply `return false;` or `return true;`. You could even do away with the `if` altogether with `return Accountnumber.Length != 15 ||  Invalidboro.Contains(Accountnumber[0]);`

Answer (score 6):

regex

```
public bool ValidateAccountNumber(string Accountnumber)
{
    return Accountnumber != null && Regex.IsMatch(Accountnumber, "^[2-7][0-9]{14}$");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You just have to combine all required checks with `&&`

```
using System.Linq;

...

// static: we don't want this in the method
public static bool ValidateAccountNumber(string Accountnumber) {
  return // Not null 
         Accountnumber != null &&
         // Contains exactly 15 characters 
         Accountnumber.Length == 15 &&
         // All characters are digits
         Accountnumber.All(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9') &&
         // Doesn't start from 0, 1, 8, 9 
       !(new char [] {'0', '1', '8', '9'}.Any(c => c == Accountnumber[0]));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I recomend you to do it in this way:

```
public bool ValidateAccountNumber(string accountNumber)
{
    var invalidBoro = new [] { '0', '1', '8', '9'};

    if (accountNumber != null && accountNumber.Length == 15)
    {
        return !invalidBoro.Contains(accountNumber[0]);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: You are right, it is better to add it in if statement.

Answer (score 1):

It checks <s>three</s> four conditions about `AccountNumber`:

- It should not be `null`
- It should have exactly 15 characters
- It should not begin with `0`, `1`, `8` or `9`
- All characters should be digits

---

```
public static bool ValidateAccountNumber(string Accountnumber )
{
    var Invalidboro = new[] { '0', '1', '8', '9'};

    return Accountnumber != null &&
           Accountnumber.Length == 15 &&
           !Invalidboro.Contains(Accountnumber[0]) &&
           Accountnumber.All(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9');
}
```

---

Just to clarify on the `!Invalidboro.Contains(Accountnumber[0])` part:

- `Invalidboro` is your array of invalid starting chars.
- We are checking if it contains the first char of `Accountnumber` (the `[0]` is the first element of an array and a `string` is an array of `char`).
- If it contains it, then it's invalid. But the method should return `true` on the valid numbers, so we negate it, with the `!`. In other words, this means: it's valid if it does not start with some invalid char.

Comment: Just so I understand:  if I have account number '012345678901234' (which is 15 digits and not null BUT does start with 0, I will get back FALSE?

Comment: Add `Accountnumber.All(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9')` condition - all characters are *digits*.

Comment: `ValidateAccountNumber` can be declared as `static`

Comment: @SeanL Yes, because `!Invalidboro.Contains(Accountnumber[0])` will return `false`

Comment: I think you mean `char.IsDigit()` because a char doesn't have a `IsDigit` propertie and your current version doesn't compile. That would also be false because there exist digits of other cultures https://dotnetfiddle.net/YxjWfr

Comment: @Toshi You are right about `IsDigit()` being a method, not a property, but I don't understood the part about `digits of other cultures`. Can you provide an example?

Comment: **1.** it must be `c => char.IsDigit(c)` or `char.IsDigit` **2.** click the link of the example I've made. There are valid Thai Digits but i'm sure OP doesn't want to have these.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the link. You are right, but the docs state that "This method determines whether a Char is a radix-10 digit" and "Valid digits are members of the UnicodeCategory.DecimalDigitNumber category". `UnicodeCategory`, for instance, states that "Decimal digit character, that is, a character in the range 0 through 9.". What are those digits you put on the string?

Comment: Thanks for the info! Now I'm certain there's nothing really simple in programming! =D

Comment: didn't want to be a nitpicker but that's how essential bugs begin :p like that webshop software which gave customers credit in case they ordered a negative number of items...